# adding a UIButton to tableView headerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to add a UIButton to a tableView, however when I do the following:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frameWidth, 200)];

UIButton *addSource = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addSource addTarget:self action:@selector(addBoard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[addSource setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addsource.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addSource setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[headerView addSubview:addSource];

self.tableView_.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

I didn't see a UIButton there. When I try using a UILabel it is there. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your addSource button does not have any frame.

Comment: what do you mean my addSource does not have any frame?

Comment: you forgot to set a frame. try `[addSource setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code ...

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

     UIButton *headername = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 270, 34)];
     headername.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
     UIImageView *tempimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300,34)];
     tempimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GrayButton.png"];
     [headerView addSubview:tempimage];
     [headerView addSubview:headername];
     return  headerView;

}
```

Comment: @xxonegirlz : Please do accept the answer if that solved your problem not for me but for the other(beginner and some one who might have same problem). So they can choose the solution and that will useful for the stack overflow as well other people.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     UIButton *name = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 120, 45)];
     name.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
     UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] init];
     UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 200,45)];
     image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];
     [header addSubview:image];
     [header addSubview:name];
     return  header;
}
```

Comment: Increase reputation by up arrow voting

Comment: What do you want to tell us with your comment??? If you want to animate people to vote your answer up, provide answers that answer the question. The OP asked for a "why", you answered with a block of code (without any explanation). I will never upvote an unexplained pure code answer (my own personal opinion).

Comment: ok don't be angry.. if there is need of explanation then i am ready to  give explain it

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

`UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 45)];`

replace it with

`UIButton *addSource = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

this will show button at 0,0 point width 100 and height 45 in header view.
this will help you

Comment: and what about @Nit's answer??

Answer (score 0):

Set frames for ur button.by defalult frame of ur button wil be CGRectZero means.width n height both wil be zero..so set its frame to draw at relative position.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{        
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 44)] autorelease]; 

    UIButton *addSource = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
    addSource.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [addSource setTitle:@"rep" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addSource addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];        

    [headerView addSubview:addSource];
    return headerView;    
}
```

Also dont forget to implement.

```
tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
```

Comment: Those frames are just for an example.customize them to your own requirement